# What is wrong with this switch statement in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to take a value from a user then every click on the button it must print statement and a picture that represent a number of trying. The if statement is working but it always shows the pic of last case.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "")
    {    
        int gussednum= Convert.ToInt16( textBox1.Text); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        {
                if (interednum < num)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Should be greater than" + num;
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case (0) :
                            Image image = Image.FromFile("1.png");
                            pictureBox1.Image = image;
                            break;

                        case (1):
                            Image im2 = Image.FromFile("2.png");
                            pictureBox1.Image = im2;
                            break;

                        case (2):
                            Image im3 = Image.FromFile("3.png");
                            pictureBox1.Image = im3;
                            break;

                        case (3):
                            Image image4 = Image.FromFile("4.png");
                            pictureBox1.Image = image4;
                            break;

                        case (4):
                            Image image5 = Image.FromFile("5.png");
                            pictureBox1.Image = image5;
                            break;

                        case (5):
                            Image image6 = Image.FromFile("dead.gif");
                            pictureBox1.Image = image6;
                            break;

                        case (6):
                            Image image7 = Image.FromFile("red.png");
                            pictureBox1.Image = image7;
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What `interednum` and `num` are? Can you provide the code were you assign them?

Comment: That's a pretty gross misuse of a switch statement. Where are `interednum` and `num` defined?

Comment: i assigned num to a random number  
 static Random R = new Random();
int num = R.Next(100);

Comment: and I take the interednum from the textBox !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've wrapped the `switch/case` with this for `loop`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
```

Whenever, the following is `true`:

```
interednum < num
```

You'll always have `i` equal to `6` because it loops to it every run.  This is why it'll always output the last `case`.

This may or may not be an issue, but worth looking at.  It seems you always change the same object (`pictureBox1`):

```
pictureBox1.Image = image7;
```

You may have more than one `pictureBox` object, so it may look like this instead:

```
pictureBox7.Image = image7;//do this for every pictureBox in every case statement
```

Comment: i removed foor and i used while ... it works thank you very much :D

Comment: No problem.  |=^]  If you feel this is a good/right answer, an upvote or check mark would be good.

Answer (score 1):

You always assign an image to pictureBox1. And obviously the last time in the loop the last switch/case is executed (#7)

```
pictureBox1.Image = image5;
```

So, you either mistyped pictureBox1 on copy/pasting, or you should break a loop as well (from your switch/case break).

I am not sure if that's even StackOverflow question but just some copy/paste issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's run in loop so it's insert first image, next second and so on until the last. Possible it's to fast to see it and that's why u see only last image. Try to debug that program to see it's true.

My advice: just change all break's commands for "return" in switch case. That's all.

Ps. This code doesn't have sense in my opinion (i saying about switch case in for loop ;)).

Comment: yup , I got it I don't need to for loop :D 
I used a while( with global var i) it is incremented every time the uset press the button